# TabControl unloads content when Visiblity is set to Collapsed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When I set `tabItem.Visiblity` to collapsed, the tab control unloads the content. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it to `Visibility.Hidden` instead, this reserves the space for the UI element, whereas Collapsed doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.check if any trigger is attached to Visibility changed. 
Also this suggests something wrong in your design. View should not hold the state, ViewModel should have the state. If state is with View only then it can loose information on visbility collapsed.